# Slow style binding in my windows store app

Tags: xaml, windows-8, windows-store-apps

I have some buttons in my xaml which I want to bind the style dynamically based on some value.  This all works great, but for maybe a second or two the buttons are not styled properly as my app is still loading.  My application will load, but I have a list view that is waiting to receive some data from a web service.  It seems as though the buttons won't be bound until the list view is bound.

Is there a way to set a "default" style on my buttons but still have my buttons bind at runtime without having to set all the properties for each button?  Or why are my buttons taking so long to bind?  Can I prioritize them?

Here is my button...

```
<Button x:Name="ButtonAll" Click="ButtonAll_Click" Style="{Binding State,Converter={StaticResource ButtonStateConverter},ConverterParameter=All}" Margin="0,0,50,0">All</Button>
```

Here is my converter code...

```
SampleState state = (SampleState)value;

SampleState param = new SampleState() { Code = (string)parameter, Name = (string) parameter };

if (state == param)
     return App.Current.Resources["TextPrimaryButtonStyle"];
else
     return App.Current.Resources["TextSecondaryButtonStyle"];
```

Comment: When you debug it, when is the conversion happening? Is the binding being triggered asynchronously? Is it being triggered twice, one for loading the page and the other for changing the value? You should try looking into using `VisualStates` for changing the content of the buttons, with the binding to the State simply triggering a state change. You may need to create a simple custom `Button` class which has a `DependencyProperty` that you can bind to.

Comment: So I ended up solving this issue in another way, using Style binding from my viewmodel instead of using a converter.  This does away with any need to do conversion on the fly.

Comment: Very nice! Add an answer outlining it, then set it as the answer.